# How can instanceof be preformed inside a method with no specific object?

Tags: java, class, object, instanceof

My code is full of things like this:

```
Block attackedBlock = (fixtureA.getUserData() instanceof  Block) ?  (Block) fixtureA.getUserData() :  (Block) fixtureB.getUserData();
Bullet bullet       = (fixtureA.getUserData() instanceof Bullet) ? (Bullet) fixtureA.getUserData() : (Bullet) fixtureB.getUserData();
```

And this works, but it's quite messy IMO, so I made a method to shorten the lines:

```
Fixture getFixture(Class USER_DATA) {
    return (fixtureA.getUserData() instanceof USER_DATA) ? fixtureA : fixtureB;
}
```

I get the error that USER_DATA isn't a class, which is understandable, but how do I make it look in the specified class? It also says that that condiotion will always evaluate to false/ What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a parameter of type `Class`, so call `getFixture(Player.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead:

```
 USER_DATA.isInstance(fixtureA.getUserData())
```

Comment: This works, however, how do I call this method?
This is the current call:
`((Interactant) getFixture(Player)).body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(4f, 1f).scl(1 / Finals.PPM), ((Interactant) getFixture(Player)).body.getWorldCenter(), true);`
But this says Expression Expected

Comment: I think you may want to post a new question for this.